# Cannot find a compatible Vulkan device or driver - Unreal Engine

Tags: opensuse, nvidia, vulkan

What I tried:

- Tried using Nouveau
- Tried installing NVIDIA drivers using Zypper
- Installed NVIDIA proprietary drivers (and uninstalled Nouveau)

I was really hoping that the proprietary drivers would fix this, but it didn't. I got the drivers from https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver.

This is the error I keep getting:

[image: Unreal Engine Vulkan device not available]

Comment: In case this helps others. I use Debian and was using nvidia drivers installed from debian packages (`apt install`, but they were not the latest ones available (`nvidia-smi` told me they're 525). I had to uninstall the drivers (complicated) and disable `nouveau`, and reinstall using the `.run` files downloaded from https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/drivers/. The error is gone for me and I use `550.54.14`.

Answer (score 5):

A way I found in order to avoid this issue and work with the Unreal Editor without messing around with graphic drivers (I am on open source drivers shipped with Linux Mint) is to launch the editor with the opengl4 flag. In this way the Vulkan requirement is skipped and the editor can start properly. Using the terminal reach the linux binaries folder `~/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux` and then use this code in order to launch the editor under Opengl4 `./UE4Editor -opengl4`

Comment: Is it necessary to be in the directory  to run this command?

Comment: To run the second one yes, you need to be in the binaries directory because the code is just looking for the UE4Editor executable in order to launch it.
There could be some more cleaver way to do it, but I am new to Linux and I am learning step by step how to deal with it and use needed software on it :)

Comment: The normal thing to do would be to type `~/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor -opengl4` from wherever you are.

Comment: Tried `opengl14` flag but another popup shows up: `Trying to force OpenGL RHI but the project does not have it in TargetedRHIs list.` and close UE4Editor...

Comment: @RichardDally https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/936174/view.html